# Python Dropbox API v2 - users_get_space_usage() does not equal value from dropbox application

Tags: dropbox-api

import dropbox  (9.4.0)

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("xxx")

print(dbx.users_get_space_usage().used)

outputs 606873703 or 592.65 MB but the dropbox client shows 578.76 MB.  This is from the webpage and the windows 10 client.

Am is using the wrong function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is due to using different factors when converting between bytes and "MB" . For reference, see the different definitions of [Megabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) vs. [Mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

- 606873703 / 1000 / 1000 = 606.87 "Megabytes"
- 606873703 / 1000 / 1024 = 592.65 "Megabytes" (with "less common" 1024000 factor) [your conversion]
- 606873703 / 1024 / 1024 = 578.76 "Mebibytes" [Dropbox's conversion]

If you want to match Dropbox's formatting, use the "Mebibyte" convention instead.

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me crazy.  I even wrote a script to loop through all the files and sum up the file size but got the same value ( 606873703 ).